# Unable to add eth0 in Rhel 7

Tags: rhel, ethernet

I am unable to find eth0 in RHEL 7 after just installation. Even I created the eth0 inside the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ directory. After created eth0 inside the network-scripts, I am unable to restarting network service. I run the command:

```
service network restart
```

The following error appears:

```
Job for network.service failed.
See systemctl status network.service and journalctl -xn for details.
```

Edit: more detail

After running the command systemctl status network.service, i will get the following error:

```
network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2014-11-24 00:02:21 IST;
  Process: 626 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 24 00:02:21 htpc.homenet network[626]: Bringing up loopback interface:[Ok]
Nov 24 00:02:21 htpc.homenet network[626]:Bringing up interface eth0 :ERROR[/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth]Device does not seem to be present,delaying initialization.
Nov 24 00:02:21 htpc.homenet network[626]:network.service:control process exited,code=exited status=1
Nov 24 00:02:21 htpc.homenet network[626]: Failed to start LSB:Bringing Up/down networking
Nov 24 00:02:21 htpc.homenet network[626]:Unit network.service entered failed state
```

Comment: Did you in fact try `systemctl status network.service` and `journalctl -xn` to see the details? Add the information from that to the question.

Comment: After running the command systemctl status network.service, i will get the following error:

Comment: Remove the changes to your network scripts and run `ip link`.  That will show you what interface you have - they are not always labeled `eth?`.

Answer (score 1):

RHEL7 uses a delightfully capricious and arbitrary device name change, to keep things sensible for the non-server or laptop version of its OS which sustain its business (which is really the advertised reason for systemd too, albeit for questionable benefit).

It sets your networking devices like `enp132s456` or so, changes them if you shuffle slots with your NIC, and without a quick fix gives anyone using Linux for the last 20 years a wonderful surprise.  But they seem to think it's for the good.

```
grep -q ifnames /etc/sysconfig/grub ||\
sed -i~ '/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/s/"$/ net.ifnames=0"/' /etc/sysconfig/grub
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
exec init 6
```

That's the fix, for now.

I hope it will continue to work as a fix, as it's a kernel thing and likely to be a feature of any new kernel we move to, systemd or no.

Comment: narrator: It was not a kernel thing.  https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt

Comment: @sourcejedi - that file is 5000 lines long.  If you can narrow it down, it would be more helpful and less like Oracle's software sequirements docs.  ;-)

Comment: You'll find this question was about RHEL7, and the net.ifnames is a boot option.  Ideally, it will be knowledge portable to whatever we move to to avoid systemd as well.

Comment: Yes, you set it at boot and [systemd-udev reads it from /proc/cmdline](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/kernel-command-line.html). Dunno if biosdevname that used to be used in RHEL6 has been modified to understand the new boot option as well -  it used to check for `biosdevname=0`.

Comment: Thank you for that input, but it's unnecessary; and it's tangential to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the network work after just disabling and restarting the NetworkManager:

```
systemctl disable NetworkManager
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Worked on Rhel7

Answer (score 0):

RHEL / CentOS 7.x uses  **consistent network device naming**.
And it might also be called *predictable network interface names*.

in any case the best way I have found to get **eth** naming back is to

- `yum remove biosdevname`
- edit `/etc/default/grub`
- append `net.ifnames=0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`
- append `biosdevname=0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` if you have *biosdevname* installed
- `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg`  {replace centos with rhel}
- reboot
- eth0 and eth1 and so on should now be there instead of the naming syntax that was used.

You do not need to mess with anything under `/etc/sysconfig/`.